# Configure Jest to support both JSX and ESM without transpiling to CJS?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, es6-modules

Is there a way to configure Jest for both ESM and JSX with only transpilation of JSX (and that to ESM)? That is, configuration for projects that are entirely ESM, have a mixture of JS and JSX files in src/ and in test/, have package dependencies with similar ESM and JSX use, *and should deploy as ESM*.

Jest's documentation on ESM configuration describes only the approach of completely disabling transform. That seems to disable JSX support (since transform is how @babel/preset-react is going to get a shot at the src). Also, an odd directive, since  disabling transforms is demonstrably wrong/unnecessary in a pure ESM, no-JSX situation. Anyway.

The common approach for Jest and ESM described in many StackOverflow posts is to use Babel's preset-env to transpile code and dependencies just for Jest. And variations on that theme. That certainly does work. Of course, if you don't want to or cannot deploy preset-env transpiled code, this approach results in testing code unlike what is deployed and that behaves/breaks in different ways.

To be clear, I'm hoping for help on configuration that works for code and dependencies that already run without issue in Node and in all browsers in just about any scenario not including Jest. I'm aware of how to setup Jest for ESM sans JSX, and of how to create a project where ESM/JSX is transpiled to CJS just for Jest. Both are pretty well covered on StackOverflow.

[Edit] To be clearer:

1. Configuring as a pure-ESM project with JSX compilation results in errors on ESM syntax.
2. Configuring with transforms off (per docs) results in errors on JSX syntax.
3. Configuration with an ESM to CJS step applied globally or applied only for Jest works. But, you're either shipping CJS or testing something other than what you shipped.

**[Update] Closing this with the conclusion it is not possible to test ESM JSX with Jest without including transpilation to CJS.** Best options seem to be accept CJS in test or to move to a different test framework.

Comment: What have you tried? Should be the same as a pure esm setup but add a react preset or just the babel transform for jsx: https://babeljs.io/docs/babel-plugin-transform-react-jsx

Comment: @morganney Added clarification at end.

Comment: Ok, but what code are we actually examining? I see no code to investigate.

Comment: Sorry, @morganney I don't follow. Are you looking for examples of JSX written with ESM imports?

Comment: If you show me some specific project code I can help. Right now you're just talking theory.

Comment: I think it's pretty clear: there are documented ways to run Jest tests on ESM code and to run Jest tests on JSX code. There's also a workaround to doing both at once that involves transpiling the ESM to CJS.

The first two are documented in Jest's own documentation, the third is well covered by a variety StackOverlow questions. I'm merely asking if there is known configuration to do the third that _does not_ rely on transpilation to CJS. Regardless, I'll close this as I think it's clear there's not an answer and this seems more like trolling at this point.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not worth the trouble.